# Iterate over a vector in matlab

Tags: matlab, vector

So I'm working on a program.  I need to iterate over a vector similar to this `sample = [0; 0; 0; 1; 1; 1 ; 0]`.  I was thinking about using loops with accumulators to build a new 2d array where column 1 is how many 0s or 1s appear and column 2 is for which token it is.  But I'm new to the syntax of matlab and checking the docs i mostly see slicing.  Any ideas about building the new matrix are welcome.

sample vector and output below

```
    arr = [0; 0; 0; 1; 1; 1; 0];
    tokenizeSignal(arr)
    ans =
    3 0
    3 1
    1 0
```

Comment: Give an example of what you expect to see as output for your input example data.

Comment: Okay, I'll update the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proposed strategy (array contains only 1 and 0) :

Initialize 2 counters

```
count_0 = 0;
count_1 = 0;
```

Iterate over the whole array arr

```
arr = [0; 0; 0; 1; 1; 1; 0];
[n,m] = size(arr); %m is espected equal to 1

y = arr[1,1]; %first element of the array, we need a reference
```

Start the loop and read the current element

```
for i=1:n
  x = arr[i,1];
```

start to count how many zeros or how many ones from the last group if the last element was zero or one

```
  if (x == 0 && y == 0)
   count_0 = count_0 + 1;
   count_1 = 0;
  else if (x == 1 && y == 1)
   count_1 = count_1 + 1;
   count_0 = 0;
  end
```

print every time the value will change (last term of a "sequence")

```
  if (x != arr[1,i+1] && count_1 > 0 && i<n)
   print(count_1, '1');
  else if (x != arr[1,i+1] && count_0 > 0 && i<n)
   print(count_0, '0');
  end
```

update the values and close the FOR loop

```
 y = x;
end
```

out of the cycle, print the last time

```
if (count_1 > 0)
 print(count_1, '1');
else if (count_0 >)
 print(count_0, '0');
end
```

Of course you can change the print with store the values in a proper array.

Comment: Wow, thank you for such a comprehensive answer.  This is fantastic--it answered other questions I had as well.

Comment: @the_martian you're welcome! And I edited a small error which had no effect if your array started with 0. Now all the code should be correct. If some problem occurs I will update the code again.